# Alternatives to secure WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I need to build a WCF service which will be consumed by several clients, including mobile apps, web client, IVR (voice recognition) etc. I want to create separate user credentials database, moreover, I want .net to create it for me along with all authentication mechanism. So far I know that such technologies as Web Matrix, ASP.NET Membership offer what I need, but is there any alternatives? What I need is:

- Auto-created membership database
- Authentication/authorization out of box (by this I mean ready-to-use methods which I can apply as attributes etc.)
- Possible social networks support ( as far as I know, this requires OAuth2 support)

Note that I almost certainly will use protocols other than HTTP, and this service won't be RESTful.

Comment: Maybe post this in [information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: it have been migrated here after I posted it in IS